# Conditional formatting with "and"

Tags: google-sheets

I have a custom formatting rule which changes the color of a series of cells. The formula is:

```
=and(I$4>=$D5,I$4<=$E5)
```

I want to add one more thing, which is to display the text in the cells which is found in C5. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

adding text in a cell with conditional formatting is not possible. you will need to add it with standard formula:

**`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(D5:D<=$I$4, E5:E>=$I$4), {C5:C}, ))`**